# Итерация и преобразование списка словарей

Tags: python, словари

Имеется список словарей

```
example = [
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1987, 7, 31)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1982, 3, 1)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1990, 3, 12)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1992, 5, 30)},
    {'bdate': None},
]
```

Необходимо его преобразовать вот в такой вид

```
        "age": {
            "0-18": 0,
            "19-35": 3,
            "36-50": 1,
            ">50": 0,
            "unknown":4
        },
```

Посоветуйте прием как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Почему `"unknown":4`, разве не 5 будет?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Кажется всё очевидно: 1. Итерируетесь в цикле по списку. 2. Для каждого элемента определяете, к какой группе он относится. 3. Инкрементируете циферку для соответствующей группы.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно высчитать текущий возраст и заполнить словарь диапазона возрастов.

Дано:

```
import datetime

example = [
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1987, 7, 31)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1982, 3, 1)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1990, 3, 12)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1992, 5, 30)},
    {'bdate': None},
]

# Модифицированная функция из: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466/5909792
def calculate_age(today, born):
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

Код:

```
ages = {
    "0-18": 0,
    "19-35": 0,
    "36-50": 0,
    ">50": 0,
    "unknown": 0
}
today = datetime.date.today()

for x in example:
    bdate = x['bdate']
    if bdate is None:
        ages['unknown'] += 1
    else:
        age = calculate_age(today, bdate)
        if 0 <= age <= 18:
            ages["0-18"] += 1
        elif 19 <= age <= 35:
            ages["19-35"] += 1
        elif 36 <= age <= 50:
            ages["36-50"] += 1
        elif age > 50:
            ages[">50"] += 1

print(ages)
# {'0-18': 0, '19-35': 3, '36-50': 1, '>50': 0, 'unknown': 5}

result = {"age": ages}
print(result)
# {'age': {'0-18': 0, '19-35': 3, '36-50': 1, '>50': 1, 'unknown': 5}}
```

---

**PS.**

Мне подсказали, что для определения возраста можно использовать сторонний модуль [python-dateutil](https://github.com/coruus/python-dateutil), пример:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
age = relativedelta(today, bdate).years
```

Comment: так будет точнее `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
age = relativedelta(today, bdate).years`

Comment: @splash58, спасибо. Посмотрел исходники и там немного по другому считаются года: https://github.com/coruus/python-dateutil/blob/60e64c6647d1c78e143638ab0b3c6f1e960e455d/dateutil/relativedelta.py#L241

Comment: да, неожиданно :)

Answer (score 1):

По-быстрому как-то вот так получается:

Исходные данные:

```
import datetime
import re

thisyear = datetime.date.today().year

res ={"age": {"0-18": 0, "19-35": 0,"36-50": 0, ">50": 0, "unknown":0}}
example = [{'bdate': None},
 {'bdate': None},
 {'bdate': None},
 {'bdate': None},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(1987, 7, 31)},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(1982, 3, 1)},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(1990, 3, 12)},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(1942, 6, 13)},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(2010, 5, 30)},
 {'bdate': None},
 {'bdate': datetime.date(1964, 8, 15)},
 {'bdate': None},]
```

ну и сам код:

```
for i in example:
    if i['bdate']:
        for k in sorted(list(res['age'].keys()))[:3]:
            _age = thisyear - i['bdate'].year
            if _age <= int(re.findall(r'\d+-(\d+)', k)[0]):
                res['age'][k] += 1
                break
            elif _age > 50:
                res['age'][">50"] += 1
                break
    else:
        res['age']['unknown'] += 1

print(res)
```

> {'age': {'0-18': 1, '19-35': 2, '36-50': 1, '>50': 2, 'unknown': 6}}

Comment: Условие `>50` не выполнилось :)

Comment: У ваc `list(res['age'].keys())[:3]` выглядит опасным для старых версий питона, на этих версиях порядок ключей в словаре может быть случайным -- из-за хешей. Да и элементов там 4, а 3. Как вариант, можно доработать `re.findall(` чтобы если он пустой, то заполняем как `>50`

Comment: Я по-другому сделал.

Comment: Спасибо, хех :)

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ с регулярками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027493/201445) подал идею о парсере диапазона лет. Анализирую строку можно понять как ее сравнивать с возрастом.

Небольшой простенький пример парсера в функции `in_range`.

Дано:

```
import datetime

example = [
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': None},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1987, 7, 31)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1982, 3, 1)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1990, 3, 12)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1992, 5, 30)},
    {'bdate': datetime.date(1964, 8, 15)},
    {'bdate': None},
]
```

Код:

```
# Модифицированная функция из: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466/5909792
def calculate_age(today, born):
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))


def in_range(age: int, range: str) -> bool:
    if range == 'unknown':
        return False

    if '-' in range:
        start, end = map(int, range.split('-'))
        return start <= age <= end
    elif range.startswith('>'):
        return age > int(range[1:])

    raise ValueError(f'Unsupported range: "{range}"')


ages = {
    "0-18": 0,
    "19-35": 0,
    "36-50": 0,
    ">50": 0,
    "unknown": 0
}

today = datetime.date.today()
ranges = ages.keys()


for x in example:
    bdate = x['bdate']
    if bdate is None:
        ages['unknown'] += 1
        continue

    age = calculate_age(today, bdate)

    for range in ranges:
        if in_range(age, range):
            ages[range] += 1

print(ages)
# {'0-18': 0, '19-35': 3, '36-50': 1, '>50': 1, 'unknown': 5}

result = {"age": ages}
print(result)
# {'age': {'0-18': 0, '19-35': 3, '36-50': 1, '>50': 1, 'unknown': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ys = [tuple(range(19)), tuple(range(19, 36)), tuple(range(36, 51))]
Keys = {Ys[0]: "0-18", Ys[1]: "19-35", Ys[2]: "36-50", True: ">50", False: "unknown"}
Result = dict.fromkeys(Keys.values(), 0)
ty = datetime.date.today().year
for d in example:
    if d['bdate']:
        age = ty - d['bdate'].year
        for years in Ys:
            if age in years:
                Result[Keys[years]] += 1
                break
        else:
            Result[Keys[age > 50]] += 1
    else:
        Result[Keys[False]] += 1
print(Result)  # {'>50': 0, 'unknown': 5, '0-18': 0, '19-35': 3, '36-50': 1}
```